# Return object without its key in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using MongoDb 3.2

Say I have this document in a MongoDb collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bad65b9777f6df3ce840fd1"),
    "entryCode" : "1234",
    "first" : {
        "someKey" : "x",
        "anotherKey" : "y"
    },
    "second" : {
        "someKey" : "u",
        "anotherKey" : "v",
    }
}
```

When I execute the following query:
`db.collection.find({entryCode:"1234"},{_id:0, first:1})`

I get this returned result:

```
{
    "first" : {
        "someKey" : "x",
        "anotherKey" : "y"
    }
}
```

However, what I'd like to return is this:

```
{
    "someKey" : "x",
    "anotherKey" : "y"
}
```

Notice I do *not* want the key `first` to be a part of the returned value. Just the object value within. What Mongo query can I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) operator, try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {   $match: { entryCode:"1234" } },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$first"
        }
    }
])
```

EDIT: In MongoDB 3.2 you can only use `$project` and specify fields explicitly:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {   $match: { entryCode:"1234" } },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            someKey: "$first.someKey",
            anotherKey: "$first.anotherKey",
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I like your answer, but unfortunately I'm using 3.2 and `$replaceRoot` is only available in 3.4. I've edited my question to clarify.

Comment: @CodyPatterson okay so then you have to use $project, modified my answer